# Tomcat shuts down on closing jar

Tags: java, tomcat, exit, shutdown, system.exit

I made a java web application that calls a main method from a jar file i included as a WebAppLibraries and when this main calls system.exit to terminate it shuts down also the web app closing tomcat. How can avoid to shut down the web app closing only the execution of that main method?

Comment: You can set set the security manager to prevent calls to System.exit. In fact, I thought all application servers did this by default, but I may be wrong on that.

Answer (score 0):

By not calling `System.exit().` Instead, call the appropriate API for shutting down web-apps for your container, which is container-specific. `System.exit()` isn't it. See the Javadoc. It's for shutting down entire JVMs, such as servlet containers.

Comment: thank you for your answer but i didn't understand how to solve. I try to explain bettere my problem: i have a jar file Ripper.jar; In my web app there is a servlet that launchs Ripper.main() and another servlet that closes the jar app calling a jar method thas has a system.exit(0). I want to close the jar but not the all web app. thank you